# The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular6

I'm attempting to start an .NET Core 2/Angular 6 SPA. I created an Angular 5 Application using "dotnet new angular" then proceeded to upgrade using [this guide](https://update.angular.io/) from angular.io. Once I finished the upgrade I tried to run the application using "dotnet run" and I get an ugly error page with the error:

> **An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**
>
> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors
> occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the
> Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Unknown
> option: '--extractCss'
>
> InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Unknown  option: '--extractCss'

Thinking perhaps I missed a step during the upgrade, I tried a second time and got the same error.

Here are the steps I took after creating the app:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
ng update @angular/core
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations hammerjs 
npm install -g rxjs-tslint
rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json
```

I'm running Node version 9.4.0 and .Net Core 2.1.200 on Windows 10 (1703) Enterprise.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Here is a full stack trace:

```
 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<StartAngularCliServerAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<StartAngularCliServerAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.<Attach>b__2_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.<WithTimeout>d__1`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.<PerformProxyRequest>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Unknown option: '--extractCss'

) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Unknown option: '--extractCss'

 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<StartAngularCliServerAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<StartAngularCliServerAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.<Attach>b__2_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: Unknown option: '--extractCss'

 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<StartAngularCliServerAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<StartAngularCliServerAsync>d__3.MoveNext()<---
<---
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For me this and the followings are solved the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10666

And also you need to edit your package.json file and remove the --extractCss parameter from the start and build property.
from:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
```

to:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
```

Comment: I am facing this same issue i apply this solution but the error remain the same

Comment: This does not work - I have removed this and it fails.   I'm also use scss

Comment: this fixed my issued too but I always end up with angular 7.2.2.... I wanted to have the 6 version as well

Comment: Not relevant for ASP.NET 3.0 and Ang 8

Comment: I got the same problem with VS 2019, ASP.NET Core 3.1 and I fix by running VS 2019 as Administrator. Hope it is helpful.

Answer (score 46):

Try to do the following

1. Open a **Powershell**
2. Navigate to the **clientapp** directory
3. Run `npm audit fix`

This works for **ReactJS** & **VueJS** projects too.

Answer (score 22):

The problem bugs me for a couple days too. Now finally get a way around. Apparently, Visual Studio tries to launch Angular CLI server for us automatically along with the ASP.Net core process. For this instance, it failed.

So according to Microsoft Doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio), we can start Angular CLI server manually.

1. navigate to the 'ClientApp' folder, and issue:

   ng serve

   to start server from the console.
2. In 'Startup.cs' file, replace

   spa.UseAngularCliServer(..)

with

```
spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
```

3. F5 to start ASP.Net Core project as we normally do.

This way you can continue debugging the application.

Comment: What if i did NOT want to run Angular app separately? Is there a way I can have dotnet build and run my Angular app using NPM ?

Comment: Note that it's important to ensure other things prior to this, too. I would start from the beginning and not assume they have done anything. You must do these things from a command prompt after downloading and installing Node.js: `dotnet new angular -o "C:\users\me\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\myproject\myproject-dev\my-project-client-app"` (add `--force` if needed after quote, if the project is someone's from GitHub, for example), then `cd` to the client-app directory of your project, then `npm install -g @angular/cli` then `npm audit fix` then `npm run ng` then `npm start`.

Answer (score 18):

In my case, I've **removed** following application setting from the azure web app and site was started working.

Key: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT 
Value: Development

Spent several days to figure out the issue :)

Comment: I wish I could vote this twice!!  Thank you, thank you!

Comment: @vapcguy - it is in the Application Settings of your Azure app service

Comment: Ok, thanks, @IsuruSiriwardana. This only helps if you're using Azure, then, but I understand why you're posting it, for those instances.

Comment: web.config contains ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable. If you do not find it in azure web app settings then you should change the value "Development" to "Production" in web.config

Comment: You are the real MVP. Love you

Answer (score 4):

If the above solution does not work, you can try the following which worked for me.

Scenario: Transferred working VS 2017 solution: core web api & angular spa projects to newly installed pc; gave me the above error.

Solution: After installing node.js workloads via visual studio installer, node.js for windows (https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and the necessary windows features for IIS; I was back on track.

The main installation is the node.js for visual studio and windows (which has npm included), had to install both for it to work. Probably the paths config for command prompt....

Answer (score 4):

Both Joe and Jays solutions work. To use the default template configuration without code changes you just need to install node.js for windows as Jay stated above and then restart VS.
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

An excellent tutorial on creating, configuring and deploying Core Angular projects with vs and vscode here . Includes IIS setup as well. 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1250961/Deploying-an-Angular-Application-with-ASP-NET-Core

Answer (score 1):

VS 2019 - Error resolved by navigating to ClientApp folder and running `npm install`. Make sure you have `npm` installed on your system along with Angular Cli. Incase having trouble installing Angular Cli you can change script from `ng serve` to `npm run start` in package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get a GitHub project working from scratch. These are the things I did to do that:

- Download and install NodeJS: https://nodejs.org/en/download
- Download any AngularJS project from GitHub
- Run a command prompt and navigate to the "client-app" folder: `dotnet new angular -o "C:\Users\me\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\myproject\myproject-dev\myproject-client-app" --force`
- Enter command: `npm install -g @angular/cli`
- Enter command: `npm build fix`
- Enter command: `npm run ng`
- Enter command: `npm start`
- Enter command: `ng start --extract-css`

(I didn't actually need to enter this last command, since `npm start` initiated this command for my project, but might not always be the case...)

In 'Startup.cs' file, replace

```
spa.UseAngularCliServer(..)
```

with

```
spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
```

Then <kbd>F5</kbd> to start the ASP .NET Core project as we normally do to start debugging the application.

After all of that, the project should run.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple Node versions installed using nvm.

You can cd into the project root in the terminal and execute

> nvm use x.x.x

This resolved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Help for me.

1. Install the node environment.js from installer vs;

2)Install node.js for your OS from the official website;

3. install npm via PowerShell. Open from the administrator, go to the Client App folder and run npm install. Then run npm audit fix (to fix errors).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and fix it by just uninstalling Nodejs from project and installing latest version of Nodejs from Nodejs.org