# Failed to deploy the app created by "dotnet new angular" to Azure

Tags: angular, azure, .net-core

I created an app using `dotnet new angular` template.

Executed `dotnet run` and everything works.

I pushed the code to GitHub and set continuous deployment in Azure to build from that GitHub repository.

However **the build fails**, I turned on Development mode in Azure to see all the errors, and this is what I get, tons of text, but I cant figure out why build failed on Azure.

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)

InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)

Stack Query Headers
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

 ))
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<TResult>.get_Result()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout<T>(Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, string message)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task<Uri> baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, bool proxy404s)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2_0+<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Show raw exception details
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

)) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.<Attach>b__2_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__278_1(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.<Attach>b__2_0(Task`1 task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__278_1(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)<---
<---
InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(string sourcePath, string npmScriptName, ILogger logger)

Show raw exception details
System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

 ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221618/the-npm-script-start-exited-without-indicating-that-the-angular-cli-was-listen

Comment: None of it helped

Comment: what did fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you setup your CI, but node.js is not installed on whatever is running this.

> The error output was: 'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: I noticed, but node as well as npm are installed on Azure