# show error when refresh page in angular and asp .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

I create the asp .net core and angular site page but when i need to refresh site it show me this error :

> One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: module.js:473\r\n\r\n      throw err;\r\n      ^\r\n\r\nError: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'\r\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)\r\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:453:25)\r\n    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:665:10)\r\n    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)\r\n    at bootstrap_node.js:607:3\r\nmodule.js:473\r\n\r\n))

Angular project and asp .net core project is separate. asp core web API and angular 8 .

**Why this error occurs ? how can I fix this error ?**

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221618/the-npm-script-start-exited-without-indicating-that-the-angular-cli-was-listen answer your question?

Comment: You can update your angular cli version. then test

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras not solved wht all answers

Comment: @kianoushdortaj try to remove last package you have installed. It's may be conflicting new package with old packages.