# Error while running ASP.NET Core with Angular Template

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am trying to run my working project in a new machine. The Angular app individually is running fine using `ng serve`, but when I am trying to rum the whole application from Visual Studio, I am getting the following error:

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: npm ERR! path C:\Windows\System32\package.json

I have tried the following ways, it didn't help:

- Selected the file package.json inside the folder ClientApp then changed the property Copy to Output Directory to Copy always.
- Deleted package.lock.json and ran npm install.
- I don't have `–EXTRACT-CSS` in my package.json. It is `"start": "ng serve`.
- Followed all the steps mentioned in https://github.com/silvairsoares/Angular-with-Asp.Net-Core/wiki

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/2154401.aspx?The+NPM+script+start+exited+without+indicating+that+the+Angular+CLI+was+listening+for+requests

Comment: @hrdkisback I have checked this. My versions are same

Comment: Have you tried this?  https://codinginfinite.com/npm-script-start-exited-without-indicating-that-angular-cli-listening-requests/

Comment: Yes. It is `"start": "ng serve"`. I didn't have ` –EXTRACT-CSS` in my package.json

Comment: Try `npm audit fix` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221618/the-npm-script-start-exited-without-indicating-that-the-angular-cli-was-listen

Comment: I tried. It didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can run your angular app inside an aspnet core app. Assuming you are running the app as a console application (Not using IIS Express) and the angular app resides inside `ClientApp` folder, you can check the following ways.

**If you want to run the angular server independently**
 add this to your `Configure()` method inside `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200"); // Use this instead to use the angular cli server
            }
        });
```

**If you want to start both of the inside the aspnet core app**
 add this to your `Configure()` method inside `Startup.cs`

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                spa.Options.StartupTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60); // Increase the timeout if angular app is taking longer to startup

            }
        });
```

> Before that make sure `npm install` inside your client app folder.

Comment: Thank you so much :) `UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer` solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

If your project code is follow,

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --extract-css",
    "build": "ng build --extract-css",
    ...
}
```

Repair follow

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.2.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.5",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.5",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
```

Comment: It is "start": "ng serve". I didn't have ` –EXTRACT-CSS` in my package

Comment: I am using Angular 7. Why should I upgrade?